# bash script: if with multiple OR condition is not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

For below script, if I am running from "abc" user, the script should not run "exit 1". Still it is running "exit 1".

```
if [ "$(whoami)" != "abc" ] || [ "$(whoami)" != "xyz" ] || [ "$(whoami)" != "pqr" ]
then
    exit 1
else
    echo "Run remaining script"
fi
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to unix.stackexchange.com. Having a series of "||" could lead to weird results.. I provided an alternative that seems more suited to what you need to achieve (and it's more readable & expendable as well), using "case"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash script seems to be working correctly to me. You are running as `abc` which means the first test is false (`abc` is equal to `abc`) so the evaluation continues to the next test which is true (`abc` is not equal to `xyz`) and the script exits because you get `false || true || true` which is `true`.

If you want to "Run remaining script" if the user is one of `abc`, `xyz`, `pqr` yu should use OR with `==` and reverse the `if` and `else` conditions or keep it the same and use AND.

So either something like this:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" != "abc" ] && [ "$(whoami)" != "xyz" ] && [ "$(whoami)" != "pqr" ]
then
    exit 1
else
    echo "Run remaining script"
fi
```

or:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" == "abc" ] || [ "$(whoami)" == "xyz" ] || [ "$(whoami)" == "pqr" ]
then
    echo "Run remaining script"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: @Abhishek if this helped you please accept it with the tick mark. That is how we say thanks here

Comment: It seems a bit excessive to run `whoami` once for each test. Better to store its output in a variable or to use a `case ... esac` statement.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to this string of ifs could be:

```
case "$(whoami)" in
   abc|xyz|pqr)  : # we do nothing here, 
                 ;; # and exit the case
   *)            exit 1  # for all other values (*) : we exit 1, terminating the script
                 ;;
esac
# here, we only continue if the case before had abc, xyz or pqr
...
```